# splitting a column and assigning header in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame where i want to split every element in the first column and assign a column header to both the new columns. right now the column has no header.it is something like:

```
                       0    1   2   3   4

A|Item Name           25   26  31  40  45
B|Item Name           26   28  29  32  50
C|Item Name           31   32  12  32  11
```

Expected output

```
 Ltr     Itm                  0    1   2   3   4

 A    Item Name              25   26  31  40  45
 B    Item Name              26   28  29  32  50
 C    Item Name              31   32  12  32  11
```

used the following code to try and convert the same:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.row.str.split('|', 1).tolist(),
                   columns=['Let', 'Itm'])
```

but got error that there is no 'row' attribute in the dataframe.

any help is much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: It looks like an index, and definitely there is no column named 'row' so the line you used won't work though the approach is mostly correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an index, you can use

```
df.index = df.index.str.split('|', expand = True)
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {'level_0': 'Ltr', 'level_1': 'Itm'})
```

You get

```
    Ltr Itm         0   1   2   3   4
0   A   Item Name   25  26  31  40  45
1   B   Item Name   26  28  29  32  50
2   C   Item Name   31  32  12  32  11
```

Comment: Thanks. worked like a charm. One more question i have is, can i also assign the column headers along with the .split function u suggested. I am sorry, i am pretty new to python and pandas.

Comment: Thank you:). If you are splitting a column instead of index, you can assign the column names directly using df[['Ltr', 'Itm']] = df.col.str.split(...) but for index, I can't think of a better way. May be reset_index first and then split

Comment: I am sorry Vaishali but I have one more question. I would also like to rename the remaining letter heads i.e. 0,1,2,3,4 to 1,2,3,4,5. I tried putting them in the .rename function. But they are not changing. Is there a way i can change it to what i want. It would be really great if you can give any advise regarding this.

Comment: If you wish to rename all the columns, the easiest would be to use df.columns=['ltr', 'itm', 1,2,3,4,5]. You can use this directly after reset index, don't use rename

Comment: just perfect, i have lot of doubts like this.... is there a way i can contact you for guidance with python and respective libraries